# Need to check whether my invercard or my graphics card is bad

Tags: graphics-card, display, external-display, dell-vostro

I have a Dell vostro 1500 laptop and my display is not working. I mean by not working is it is not showing anything on the screen except some vertical lines..when i connected the external monitor it didnot show up. Then I disconnected the display and then connected the external monitor and it started showing up on external monitor. I tried changing the display and the display connecting cable but doesnt make any difference. Now I think the problem might be either inverter card or graphics card..could anyone tell me how to determine which one is the problem!!!!!!! thanks for al your help in advance....